# Android: onKeyListener() doesn't execute for power button

Tags: android

I'm working on a thing where I need to listen to the power and volume buttons in a Fragment when pressed. I did this successfully with the volume button, however, when pressing the power button the screen turns off and my code doesn't execute.

```
view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {

                p = true; //value assigned here!
                return true;

            } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {

                m = true; //value is not assigned here :/
                return true;

            }
}
```

Any idea how to get my code to execute when power button is pressed?

Comment: Have you added the permission in manifest file?

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In earlier version of android pressing **Power Key** would trigger `KeyListener` but in recent version (around Kitkat) Pressing **Power Key** only result in turning device screen on/off.

You can no longer detect **Power Key** press but you can track device screen turning on/off from `Activity` by listening to `onStart()` and `onStop()` **callbacks** or listening to `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` or `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` **broadcasts** from `Service` or `BroadcastListener`.